# Problema al girar personaje en Unity 2D

Tags: unity, animación, unity2d

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando giro a mi personaje en unity con la siguiente función

```
    if (direccion < 0 && izq)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up);
        izq = false;
        der = true;

    }
    else if (direccion > 0 && der)
    {

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0, Vector3.up);
        izq = true;
         der = false;

    }
```

Pero ahora resulta que cuando gira a la izquierda el personaje aparece cortado a la mitad pero en la ventana "Game" ya que en la ventana de "Scene" aparece normal y lo extraño es que cuando vuelve a su posición inicial aparece completo,
ahora si mi pregunta es.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque me odia unity U":? jaajjaj Real mente no le encuentro mas explicación a lo que pasa por que si modifico manualmente los valores de la rotación cuando reproduzco el juego ahí si aparece completo :"C.
Así que por favor si alguien que pasa se lo pido realmente me lo explique estoy a punto de reinstalar unity porque no le encuentro mas sentido que no esta funcionando bien.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: No puedo utilizar la función del SpriteRender flipX por motivos estéticos(la boca se queda estática donde esta porque es un objeto aparte).

Comment: ya revisaste que tu camara o los objetos padres del personaje no tengan rotación que haga que no se vea la profundidad completa del personaje?, esto podrías arreglarlo alejando en profundidad el escenario, es decir si camara la tienes en z-10 y personaje en z0 pon a escenario en z10, entre mayor z más alejado de la camara.

Comment: Lofiu <3 jajajaja 
Si eso era todo XD jajaja al parecer cuando rotados y como la cámara estaba exentamente en la misma posición no aparecían en cámara ya hice que abarcara mas espacio y aparecieron.
Muchas gracias :*

Comment: Ok, entonces lo pongo como respuesta y porfa selecciónala como la correcta. De nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa el orden y posiciones de los objetos con respecto a la camara, al rotar objetos en y es probable que la profundidad se vea afectada si la camara no esta lo suficientemente alejada de los objetos, buenas practicas es poner camara en z-20, escenarios en z0 y elementos en los niveles -1:-19